# Why only one .class file is created in java & which is declared first?

Tags: java, .class-file

In Java:

```java
class A{}
class a{}
```

after compilation : A.class

```java
class a{}
class A{}
```

after compilation : a.class

Why only one class created?
the first we declared only that .class file generated

Please explain the reason in detail.

Comment: Are you running on Windows, by any chance? If so, the file system is case-insensitive, so you *can't* create both `A.class` and `a.class`. On a case-sensitive file-system, I'd expect both files to be created.

Comment: As a side-note, please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and preview your post carefully before submitting - all your code was written as non-code, and all your non-code was written as code. (I've fixed it for you now.)

Answer (score -4):

Historically in Java, the name (and case) of the "main" **public** class of the file had to match the file name. So public class A has to be in the file A.java and will compile into A.class and you will run it's main() method using "java A". we have to name the class and the file the same way.

The second class in the file is not public (implicitly protected since no modifier was given) and is not nested under the A class. no one outside the package of class A will be able to use it. therefore it does not need its' own class file.

That is Java's way of implementing the principle of "Encapsulation". you could create classes and sub-classes in your code, and anyone who receives the compiled products of these classes will not be able to see the internal structure of your code.

Comment: Downvoted because this is nonsense. Every class in Java **must be** in its own class file - the [class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) doesn't allow storing more than one class in it.

Comment: that is incorrect. you can have multiple classes in a file. public classes and static nested classes get their own file.

Comment: the code the OP wrote produces only one .class file, but it will not run if any class tries to use the package protected class.

Comment: @ThomasKläger+ more exactly, each toplevel class and each nested class (static, nonstatic, local, or anonymous) gets a separate file; nested classes have names like `Foo$Sub.class` and `Foo$1.class` so their files don't conflict. It's toplevel classes with different case that conflict on a case-insensitive filesystem like Windows. Also, Java itself does NOT require the _source_ file be publictoplevelname.java although this is _recommended_ and IDEs or other tools often do require it.

Comment: You can have multiple classes in a source file (".java" file), but the compiler produces as class file (".class" file) for every class. In the OPs case it is the file system (Windows) that doesn't allow the two files "A.class" and "a.class" to exist at the same time - on Linux and MacOS this is allowed and works.

Comment: @ThomasKläger On Windows it might work as well, as you can configure NTFS to use case-sensitive filenames (this can be configured *per directory*, but the default is case-insensitive filenames.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Java itself actually requires the filename to have the same name as the public class defined in it, otherwise you get a _javac_ error _"X.java:1: error: class Y is public, should be declared in a file named Y.java"_ On the other hand, if there is no public class in a .java file, then you can name it anything you want.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel except when you use the feature of running a source file directly (compiling on-the-fly) via `java Source.java`. Then, the source file is allowed to contain multiple public top level classes.

Comment: @Holger Really? That sounds like a weird and unnecessary relaxation of the rules.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it has always been an *optional* restriction. See [the oldest specification still online](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/packages.html#73491): “*When packages are stored in a file system (§7.2.1), the host system **may choose** to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav)…*”

Comment: @Holger True that may be, but I was talking about the relaxation of the rules between `java` compared to `javac`. If you use `javac` on that same file, you'll get error _"Multi.java:9: error: class Other is public, should be declared in a file named Other.java"_, while `java` will just work.